# Chronolocation - describe a temporal equivalent for Geolocation

Tags: datetime, geolocation

> "Geolocation is the identification of the real-world geographic location of an object. Geolocation may refer to the practice of assessing the location, or to the actual assessed location." -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation

Is there a standard way to describe temporal locations/coordinates that extend beyond Unix timestamps?  If not, please suggest or describe an outline for one. Such a system would formalize times like:

1. -13,750,000,000 ± 11,000,000 (Big Bang)
2. 1970-01-01:00:00:00 (Unix Epoch)
3. 1 (Year 1 CE)

For example: both Geolocations and Chronolocations frequently lack precision -- this is just one consideration but I'm sure there are more.

My goal is to formalize a way to store and retrieve temporal locations of all kinds. As you might imagine this is more complex than it sounds.

Comment: Museum worker: "This dinosaur is 67,000,012 years old." Sceptic: "How do you know about the 12?" Museum worker: "Well, it was 67,000,000 years old when I started working here 12 years ago!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of such a system, but it would be fairly trivial to write a class where a structured data type like this exists:

```
struct bigTime{
 signed long int millenium;
 int decade;
 signed long int seconds;
}time;
```

You could store milennia before/after an arbitrary point (even 1970 for simplicity) for long range, decades for mid range, then use seconds and milliseconds as short term.

You could create a class where adding +/- $X seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years, decades, centuries, millenia would be straightforward.

```
Say you wanted to go 156 years back. that's -15 decades and -189 341 556 seconds. 

Or 3205 years and 2 weeks and a day back. That's -3 millenia, -20 decades, -159 080 630 seconds.

Or even 67,000,012 years (from jonathan's offtopic joke). That's -67000 millenia, -1 decade -63 113 851.9 seconds.
```

All of those are from today, but would be from whatever arbitrary point you chose.

The system I describe would give you 4.2 Trillion years to work with either way down to the millisecond, and more or less minimize memory required. (I'm sure it could be brought down more if you tried)

Comment: You should probably pin it to some arbitrary date as 0. So maybe pin it to unix timestamps. Anything 'current' would have an actual time that the existing libraries could manipulate, you can traverse the Julian and Gregorian calendars correctly. Geolocation as a 0,0 point.

Comment: That's what I meant by before/after an arbitrary point, and even 1970 for simplicity. It was late when I wrote that.

Comment: Thanks for this thought out answer -- I prefer your divisions into millenia, decades, and seconds over what I had in mind. I'm guessing it won't be hard to store the data this way and recombine it into a Unix timestamp on the way out if necessary. One question -- rather than store a signed integer for each value, I think I'll store the sign in a separate field. Can you think of any problems with this approach?

Comment: That wouldn't really cause any problems. If anything using an unsigned long int and a seperate sign field would give you twice the range for millenia. You don't need it for the decades or seconds though.